# Update WebBrowser in Delphi

Tags: delphi

Hi I am making a web browser in delphi, so for now I'm doing is letting the user can modify the headers at will, the current problem is that I use a checkbox to check when the user wants to use the headers that are in a memo the problem is that when I use it for the first time it works fine but when I disable the checkbox and try to use the browser without the headers is that the headers are still active and that should not be happening.

The code page used to test local

```
<? php

$ nav = $ _SERVER ['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

echo "<h1> Test:". $ nav. "</ h1>";

?>
```

The code delpi

```
TForm2.sButton1Click procedure (Sender: TObject);
var
   Flags, Headers, targetFrameName, PostData: OleVariant;
   Url, Ref: string;
begin

   Flags: = '1 ';
   TargetFrameName: ='';
   PostData: ='';
   URL: = sEdit1.Text;

   if (sCheckBox1.Checked) then
   begin
   Headers: = sMemo1.Text;
   WebBrowser1.Navigate (URL, Flags, targetFrameName, PostData, Headers);
   end
   else
   begin
   Headers: ='';
   WebBrowser1.Navigate (URL, Flags, targetFrameName, PostData, Headers);

   end;

end;
```

Comment: You want to refresh the actual page?

Comment: I'm having a very difficult time understanding what you're trying to do

Comment: I just want to avoid is that the headers are repeated because when I browse and use the option standard headers, the header is active in the webbrowser

Comment: I think you are seeing caching behaviour from IE. Have you tried adding the no cache meta tag to your web page? (`<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Echo the time in the PHP code to ensure that the server is getting hit each time. In addition, take a look at the flags `navNoReadFromCache` and `navNoWriteToCache` to control caching.

Read more about [Navigate](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/SHDocVw.TWebBrowser.Navigate) and the [WebBrowser control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752093%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).